# Accessing OS Dialog from VBScript

Tags: excel, pdf, vbscript, vba

I am trying to automate a webpage save as pdf via a VBScript from developer in MSEXCEL. So what I am doing is as soon as the page displays I am using sendkeys CTRL + P to call print dialog box and using another sendkey ENTER to click on print as Adobe PDF so the next dialog is a save as pdf which needs to be clicked on save button to save. But this dialog is an OS dialog and using sendkeys isn't helping. Please help me as it is just a small thing to be resolved.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try if you can send TAB and hit the ENTER on focus to SAVE button

Comment: Save is already focussed but using TAB reflect a tab in browser not on the save dialog box

Answer (score 0):

@amisha: Probably you can try it by handling with the help of AUTOIT script. Autoit is an external script and a free ware to do the windows automation. So basically write the code in AUTOIT to handle this and execute it the MS Excel like an example shown below,

```
Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

process_name= wsh.Run("D:\Program Files\autoit-v3\install\AutoIt3_x64.exe "_& xPath & "\handler.au3", 0, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

set objWsh = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
objWsh.run """Acrobat.exe"" /p /h" &FileName,,true

This will elliminate the need to send keystrokes. Best of luck!